# Dynamically determine PHP based CMS compatability with servers?

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system

I'm working on the installation wizard for my php-based CMS.

Currently, I'm checking for the php version, which must be >= 5.4 as well as whether apache_get_modules is available, if so, check whether mod_rewrite is enabled.

There are 3 possible outcomes. Success, warning and error.

Success and error should be pretty self-explanatory.

Warning is when the installation wizard is unable to figure out certain things, so we don't know exactly if it works or not.

It looks like this:
[image]

So, question is. What more can I check for?

I guess I can test for a few extensions, like GD Imagelibrary.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: "What more can I check for?" Erm... the things that your CMS relies on? What else would you have to check on?

Comment: access rights for the directories your software will use, php configuration wrt security. Have a look at how other successful CMSes do!

Comment: I hate frameworks telling me i cant install this or that , you should just warn your users but let them try to perform the installation. then if it fails it fails , just display a log  , but dont disable the install button because i dont have the right version of php because of a function you'd use once in all your CMS , that's just dreadfull ...

Comment: I agree mpm. That's why there are 3 levels. Green: everything will work 100%, yellow: some functionality will not be optimal or red: nothing will work at all. (Some of the core systems depend totally on 5.4, so it will not run whatsoever) :P

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what CMS you are trying to install but my advice would be to go to the website for that CMS and find their requirements page. It should tell you what the server requirements are. Compare those requirements with what your web host offers and see what is missing. You may need to create a simple phpinfo file that will tell you what modules your hosting server has installed. If you don't see an issue there, check for permission conflicts on the different directories associated with the CMS.

Comment: The person asking the question is writing a CMS, not installing one.

Comment: Yea... I guess I missed that initially.